# How to give ui-select border CSS on focus

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-select, form-control

I am using `ui-select` for the first time and I have tried all combination in its css file to give the border css like `form-control` class but so far not successful.

Here' the image demo 
[image]

I want something like the input box to be in around my `ui-select`. Please help me in learning something new.

Comment: Use the Developer Console to inspect the element. Force the element to the focus state. The CSS classes involved should be apparent.

Comment: I have already tried with various classes like `ui-select-container` `selectize-control `and many more, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

## Adding custom colours to input and select boxes

by adding a border and outline you should get about the same look as in your picture.

1. 0.6em padding to the input and select boxes. (em is % of text size)
2. Border and outline are a blue color. The outline is slightly transparent.

Here is an example:

```css
form {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fancy-form-input label span {
  color: red;
}

.fancy-form-input label {
  display: block;
}

.fancy-form-input {
  margin: 1em 1em;
}

.fancy-form-input label,
.fancy-form-input input,
.fancy-form-input select {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0.3em 0;
}


/*here is the blue input*/

.fancy-form-input input,
.fancy-form-input select {
  padding: 0.6em;
  border: 1px solid rgba(138, 212, 238);
  outline: 3px solid rgba(138, 212, 238, 0.5);
}

.fancy-form-input select {
  width: calc(210px + 0.6em);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="fancy-form-input">
    <label>Sublocation Name<span>*</span></label>
    <input placeholder="Enter sublocation name" />
  </div>

  <div class="fancy-form-input">
    <label>Location<span>*</span></label>
    <select>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="fancy-form-input">
    <label>Status<span>*</span></label>
    <select>
      <option>test</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```